# How can I resize an image without changing the colors in an image?

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I have a folder of images for a computer vision task. Each image is a segmentation mask. This means each pixels color represents which class the pixel represents. Now I would like to scale the images smaller.

However, if I do

```
for i in *.png; do convert $i -resize 621x188! $i; done
```

I have the problem that some colors in the boundary get interpolated. How can I disable this?

Comment: By the way, you can use `mogrify -sample ... *.png` to save writing a loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do the resize with `-sample` this will remove or duplicate rows/columns so the colours are identical

[imagemagik](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/resize/#sample)

```
for i in *.png; do convert $i -sample 621x188! $i; done
```

Answer (score 0):

This script will do the thing, hope it's the simplest possible way.

```
convert *.png -sample 621x188! -set filename:f '%t' '%[filename:f].png'
```